# Wordpress - How can i have featured categorized post not mix with the main postings

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

Im using wordpress with twentyfourteen as theme. On the right sidebar, I already have widget that show top latest featured post. Therefore, I want to remove  featured post from main posting to avoid duplicate.[Here is the link to my website](http://harta.net/)

[image: duplicate in main posting section and latest featured post section]

Example above, you can see the "PROPERTY LAUNCH" post is duplicated on the main posting and on the featured posting on the right.

How can I resolve this so featured categorized post does not appear in main posting ?

Comment: make your one of the page main page instead of post  admin-setting-reading then choose static page with sidebar

Comment: im sorry what do you mean ? can we have featured posting (currently categorized as featured) on the right side. and that those featured categorized post not included in the main posting stream like you see in the middle

Comment: If I make static page, then the new post wont be autoput there in mainpage right and we need to put new post manually right?

Answer (score 0):

After googling for few more hours I finally found solution to my question from this [wp explorer](https://www.wpexplorer.com/hide-posts-wordpress-homepage/) website . This code will remove post from featured categories from appearing in main posting .

```
 function exclude_category($query) {
        if ( is_home() ) {
            $query->set( 'cat', '-23' ); //23 refers to the my featured category id
        }
        return $query;
    }
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```